# Construction of Riemann Sphere $C_{\infty}$ in Miranda's "Algebraic curves"

Tags: algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I have a question about some steps in the construction of $C_{\infty}$ in an excerpt of Miranda's "Algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces" (page 61):

[image]

That's not clear to me how the map $\pi:Z \to C_{\infty}$ arises from the meromorphic function $x$ on $X$ and why does $\pi$ has degree $2$?

Comment: The section you're quoting doesn't have anything to do with constructing the Riemann sphere $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$, it's about constructing *hyperelliptic* Riemann surfaces. The sentence about the Riemann sphere was just a short remark at the end of the *previous* section.

Comment: Sorry, for misunderstanding expression, indeed $\pi$ is considered as a map which continue to hyperellictic RS $Z$ mapping into Riemann sphere